# Programaticallt Setting an Excel Cell Value that has Validation on it

Tags: excel, validation, automation

I have an application that populates an Excel file with data.  One of the cells being populated has Cell Validation on it based on a list.  When the populated form is opened, I am seeing that  my application populates the cell, the value is being seen as invalid, despite the value being in the list.

I am populating the cell value in this manner:

```
mainSheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] = cellValue;
```

Does anyone know what information I am missing to set a cell value to a valid value?

Comment: What indication are you getting that the value is invalid?

Comment: Please post what the error is. Tks

Comment: The error is that the cell is circled in red.  Just like what happens when you enter an invalid value into a cell with validation.  The proble is that the value is NOT invalid.  The value being populated into the cell via code *IS* a valid value for the associated list.

Comment: I have re-done the application to use a local sub in the excel sheet to do the cell update but it still results in valid values for the cell showing as invalid by the cell being circled in red.

Comment: ...wrong section to post the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. The code was populating the cell with a STRING value. The linked list to the drop down consisted only of INTEGER values. STRING <> INTEGER so the DV routines were reporting a failure. Populating the cell with an INT value resulted in success.